# Bug on a band problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]
I have encountered this problem on excercises for feynman lectures online website. This is the question: 
An infinitely stretchable rubber band has one end nailed to a wall, while the other end is pulled away from the wall at the rate of 1 m/s;  initially the band is 1 meter long. A bug on the rubber band, initially near the wall end, is crawling toward the other end at the rate of 0.001 cm/s. Will the bug ever reach the other end? If so, when?

First i labeled some quantities. $x(t)$ is the distance of the bug from the wall at any time t. $y(t)$ is the distance from the wall of the right end of the rubber band. $y'(t)$ is a constant and is $v$. The bug's velocity 0.001cm/s is given $a$. No what we want to find is $x'(t)$.

If the bug is not crawling but standing still on the rubber band at $x$, it still be travelling away from the wall with velocity $\frac{x v}{y}$. Now at that instant bug is also crawling with $a$. Then $$x'(t) = a + \frac{xv}{y}$$. Now $y = v t + 1$. $$x'(t) = \frac{v}{vt+1}x + a$$. This is a linear ODE, therefore integration factor is $e^{\int\frac{v}{vt+1} dt} = vt + 1$.$$x = \frac{1}{vt+1} \int a(vt+1) dt$$$$x = \frac{a}{vt+1} (\frac{v t^2}{2} + t)$$.The bug reaches the end of rubber band when $x=y$.$$\frac{a}{vt+1} (\frac{v t^2}{2} + t) = vt+1$$. Which gives the quadratic equation$$t^2(av-2v^2) + t(2a - 4v) - 2 = 0$$$$t = \frac{-1}{v} \pm \frac{\sqrt{a^2 - 2av}}{av-2v^2}$$ Which has solution when $a \gt 2v$. Please tell me where i went wrong.

Comment: I think your solution is correct. If you think about the actual problem, the worm is travelling so slowly in comparison to the stretching of the band, that it is no surprise that it does not reach the end.

Comment: Bug actually reach the end. The solution is given in the website. But i'm trying to find the problem with my approach.

Comment: Where is the website? Can you link it?

Comment: http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/info/exercises/bug_on_band.html

Answer (score 0):

Up to where you identify the ordinary differential equation looks good.

Your solution, x(t) has the factor a that is not in both terms of x'(t), so that doesn't look good.

The problem can be considered in simpler terms and you can use the simpler solution as a check.

Any segment, s, of rubber band in front of the bug grows at a rate s' = (s/length of rubber band)*1 m/s.  Note that you can pick s and length of rubber band at any given time.  The ratio is constant.

The bug crawls past the rubber band in front of him at 0.00001 m/s. He will not reach the tip unless he starts out pretty close to the tip.

To generalize it, compare the rate, at which, the rubber band in front of the bug grows, (s/L)*Vtip, to the rate, at which, the bug moves, Vbug.

(s/L)*Vtip > Vbug, then tip gets farther and farther away.

(s/L)*Vtip = Vbug, then tip gets away as fast as bug moves closer.

(s/L)*Vtip < Vbug, then bug makes it to tip.

Comment: No actually the bug will reach the end. It is that solution that i couldn't get to.

Comment: You are right.  I rashly shot out an incorrect simplified answer.